# When to use the Jacobian $\cal J$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble with how and when to set up a Jacobian. For instance, if I need to find the integral of some function $H(f(x),g(x))dx$. If I let $f(x)=u$ and $g(x)=v$ then I should, I think, have some function $\int\mathcal{J}_H(u,v) d(u,v)$ which is equivalent to my original $\int H(f(x),g(x))dx$  right? Or am I missing something.

*Edit*

For example (as requested)

This is an example, please don’t try to solve it.

$$\int H(f(x)g(x)) = \int \frac {dx}{x(x-2)} = \int x^{-1}(x-2)^{-1} dx$$

Now I know I can use partial decomposition, or trig-sub, but I wanted to see if I could do it this way. So bear with me.

If

*Let: $u=x$, $du=dx$; $v=x-2$; $dv=x$*

Then, by the product rule, I have $$\int (uv)^{-1}duv=d(uv)= v du+ u dv$$

So$\ldots$ $$\int (uv)^{-1}(vdu+udv) = \int \left(\frac {du}{u}+ \frac {dv}{v}\right)d(uv) = \ln|x|+\ln|x-2|$$

That is not correct of course. The correct answer being $$\frac 12 \ln\left|\frac{x-2}{x}\right|+C$$ but it is close enough to beg the question; What factor is missing? That got me thinking, the factor I am missing might be the Jacobian $\cal J$. Hence the question.

Comment: Your parentheses don't make sense in either the first or the last expressions involving $H$. What is your proposed Jacobian?

Comment: If you have one on hand, an explicit example will probably be more enlightening than working in abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  If you're starting out with a function $H$ and a vector-valued function $f$ then

$$\int H\bigl( f(x) \bigr) dx = \int \frac{ H(u) }{ \bigl|J_f\bigl( f^{-1}(u) \bigr)\bigr| } du,$$

assuming that $f$ is invertible, which requires (among other things) that $x$ has the same dimension as $f$.  $|\cdot|$ is the determinant here.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for thanks. Short sweet and not a lot of math. Pardon my ignorance but can you edit and expand your answer a bit (I would like to understand the process) or give me a link to the proof?

Comment: Most calculus texts will contain a better explanation than I would provide.  Look for `change of variables' in multiple integrals.